# How to stop marking while in tmux copy-mode?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux

I want to mark and copy text, and then stay in copy-mode with the marker off, permitting me to move up/down without marking new text (see below).

But after marking text and pressing `space` or `y` to copy it, the mark stays on, so that moving the cursor marks new text. How can I avoid that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the text selection in copy mode without yanking (copying to the buffer) the text press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. You should remain in copy mode at this point and be able to move the cursor and select other text or exit.

If you want to yank and exit, use <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will yank the selected text and exit copy mode.

If you want to yank and remain in copy mode with the text still selected, <kbd>y</kbd> should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! So "y" and then "Esc" will allow me to yank and then move around, from the point where text was yanked, without marking other text?

Comment: Do your answer assume "vi" mode?

Comment: It's wierd that after pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then the selection dissapears, but it starts selecting text again if moving the cursor?

Comment: @Shuzheng, Yeah, this answer assumes "vi" mode. My `.tmux.conf` file contains this setting: `setw -g mode-keys vi`.

Comment: In my tmux, the selection is cleared, but when you start to move around, it starts to select again :/

Comment: @Shuzheng what version of tumx are you running? I seem to remember this happening to me on older versions.

Comment: On Debian, where it's not working, I run tmux 2.8. However, you answer works fine on my Macbook; however, I cannot see the tmux version there right now. I installed tmux on macOS using brew, so it's probably the newest.

Comment: Strange. This is working on tmux 2.7 for me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, hitting <ESC>  does not disable visual line mode for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I had tmux version 2.8 installed. I built the latest version (3.1b) from source on my Debian 10 machine and the issue seems to be resolved.